# Website keeps requesting a 301 URL address

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, http-status-code-301

My website is giving me a "This website is not secure" and I can't find the root of it, even though I double checked through everything to see if there are any http and switched them to https. I also have cloudflare forcing https.

[image: 1]

I have checked the network tab and found one URL giving me trouble but it doesn't give me much information

[image: 2]

The URL is giving a 301 moved permanently. I don't know where in my html I am requesting this site. I even used ctrl + f nothing showed up.

[image: 3]

It's just requesting http://mywebsite.com/ but there is nothing I can see in my html requesting a http version of my site. I don't have anything that would cause my website to request http in .htaccess either.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteRule ^folder/?$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]

ErrorDocument 403 /index.html 
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html 
ErrorDocument 500 /index.html 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/403/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You will need to post your html markup and maybe js logic. We cannot somehow magically guess what your content might be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It looks like it was jQuery that was requesting a http version of my site.

I couldn't ctrl + f it because it was a cloudflare jQuery link.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
```

On line 2727 it was checking using http. (The picture shows https is because I just changed it)
[image: 1]

### The Fix

---

1. Save the jQuery locally and change http to https.